# why is the data not getting displayed using react native snap carousel

Tags: javascript, react-native

data is not getting displayed while using react native snap carousel

I have done this like :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const images = [
  require('./Images/logo-chepauk.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-dindigul.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-kanchi.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-karaikudi.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-kovai.png'),
  require('./Images/logomadurai.png'),
  require('./Images/logothiruvallur.png'),
  require('./Images/logotuti.png'),
];

class TeamScroll extends Component {
  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <Image source={item} style={styles.logoStyle} />;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View
          style={{
            transform: [
              {
                rotate: '-14deg',
              },
            ],
          }}>
          <Carousel
            inactiveSlideOpacity={0.6}
            inactiveSlideScale={0.65}
            firstItem={1}
            sliderWidth={width}
            itemWidth={width / 3}
            data={images}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
          />{' '}
        </View>{' '}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  logoStyle: {
    transform: [
      {
        rotate: '14deg',
      },
    ],
    width: width / 3,
    height: width / 3,
  },
};

export default TeamScroll;
```

the 8 different images that I use in the array is the data that I need to show the user but with this procedure data is not shown
I want do this using data and renderItem props in the carousel
Is there anything wrong that I have done in my code in accessing these data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried your code with remote images and didn't have any issue. Are you sure that the images you're trying to display are properly located in your project tree?

Here is the result:

[image: react-native-snap-carousel]

You can find the updated code below. Note that I added `{ overflow: 'visible' }` to prevent the slides from being cut out.

By the way, I don't know which code format you're following, but you're pretty far from React's standards, which makes your code almost impossible to read. I recommend you to take a look at a few React Native's [examples](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) and [plugins](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) in order to get familiar with React's code formatting. You can even use [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) if you need help with that.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const images = [
  'https://unsplash.it/300/?random',
  'https://unsplash.it/350/?random',
  'https://unsplash.it/400/?random',
  'https://unsplash.it/450/?random',
  'https://unsplash.it/500/?random',
  'https://unsplash.it/550/?random',
  'https://unsplash.it/600/?random',
];

class TeamScroll extends Component {
  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <Image source={{ uri: item }} style={styles.logoStyle} />;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View
          style={{
            transform: [
              {
                rotate: '-14deg',
              },
            ],
          }}>
          <Carousel
            inactiveSlideOpacity={0.6}
            inactiveSlideScale={0.65}
            firstItem={1}
            sliderWidth={width}
            itemWidth={width / 3}
            data={images}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            containerCustomStyle={{ overflow: 'visible' }}
            contentContainerCustomStyle={{ overflow: 'visible' }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logoStyle: {
    transform: [
      {
        rotate: '14deg',
      },
    ],
    width: width / 3,
    height: width / 3,
  },
});

export default TeamScroll;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the plugin but, as already stated, with your images' path. To prevent such issues, you should define a name for your app in your `package.json` file: `{ "name": "app" }`. Then, you'll be able to require your local images this way: `require('app/path/to/your/image.jpg');`